# How does a flashlight work? How would that be effected in the vacuum of space or on another planet?

Tags: visible-light

I was wondering if it was possible to explore the dark side of the moon. I've been trying to figure out a light source so things there can be seen.

Comment: Is this a joke question? The moon has day and night similar to earth. In addition, any light source would do.

Comment: Sorry. Not a joke, I just was told that a flashlight wouldn't work and was wondering and couldn't find any information. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we call the "dark side" of the moon is just the side that is not visible from Earth. That side is illuminated by the sun just as often as the side that we can see. But when it is in the light, we don't see it.

As for your other question: conventional flashlights work by sending a current through a light source (incandescent bulb, or these days increasingly LEDs). Either of these will work fine in vacuum.

Comment: I'd be concerned with battery leakage in a vacuum.

Comment: @M.Enns - sure you can be concerned... but see for example http://www.citizensinspace.org/2014/02/a-small-vacuum-chamber-test-facility/ which ran a test on an ordinary 9 V battery for five minutes with no ill effects, or [this NASA paper](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20060020764.pdf) which tests LiPo batteries in vacuum